# 'yarn install' not fetching from Nexus npm registry

Tags: yarnpkg, nexus

Yarn (1.22.19) always fetches dependencies from https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ instead going through the configured registry.

My project has `.npmrc` configured with:

```
registry=https://my.server/nexus/repository/npm-group/
```

In the npm-group there is a yarn-proxy configured to map registry.yarnpkg.com (img below)

Yarn config commands show the repo is correctly configured

```
 $ yarn config get registry
https://my.server/nexus/repository/npm-group/

 $ npm config list -l
...
registry = "https://my.server/nexus/repository/npm-group/"
```

Yet Yarn install is not using Nexus

```
 $ yarn install --verbose
...
verbose 0.466634708 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/es-abstract/-/es-abstract-1.20.1.tgz".
```

I see other commands like `yarn add` actually going to Nexus.

I can see references to `registry.yarnpkg.com` in `node_modules/../yarn.lock` files

Any idea what the issue could be?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a `.yarnrc` file:

```
registry "https://my.server/nexus/repository/npm-group/"
```

According to my research:

- [yarnpkg/yarn#606](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/606)
- [yarnpkg/yarn#871](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/871)

There still appear to be some problems in this area. You might just have to use npm.